Given a diagonal matrix, how can we find its smith normal form?
Suppose we have a diagonal matrix $$A={\rm diag} \{k_1,\dots,k_n\},$$
where $k_i\in \mathbb{N}^+$, is there any way to describe the smith normal form of $A$?
As far as I am concerned, the only thing that I can get is the $(1,1)$-entry of the smith normal form of $A$ is the great common divisor of $\{k_1,\dots,k_n\}$. Any advice will be appreciated.

$\def\ed{\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}}$
For $\ i>1\ $ the $\ i^\text{th}\ $ entry on the diagonal of the Smith normal form of a Matrix with integer entries is the ratio of the gcd of its minors of  order $\ i\ $ to the gcd of its  minors of order $\ i-1\ ,$ provided at least one of these latter is non-zero$.^\color{red}{\dagger}$ If all the minors of some order $\ j\ $ are zero, then so are all those of orders greater than $\ j\ $ and so is the $\ i^\text{th}\ $ entry on the diagonal of the Smith normal form for any $\ i>j\ .^\color{red}{\dagger}$
If $\ A\ $ is an $\ n\times m\ $ matrix with entry $\ a_{ij}\ $ in its $\ i^\text{th}\ $ row and $\ j^\text{th}\ $ column, then a minor of order $\ t\ $ of $\ A\ $ is the determinant of a $\ t\times t\ $ submatrix of $\ A\ .$ The entries of any such submatrix must be of the form $\ a_{r_ic_j}\ ,$ where $\ 1\le$$\,r_1<$$\, r_2<$$\,\dots< r_t\le n\ $ and $\ 1\le c_1< c_2<\dots< c_t\le m\ .$ Let $\ A_{t\times t}\ $ be this submatrix
If   $\ A=$$\,\text{diag}\big\{k_1,$$\,k_2,$$\,\dots,$$\,k_n\big\}\ $ is an $\ n\times n\ $ diagonal matrix, then $\ a_{r_ic_j}=k_{r_i}\delta_{r_ic_j}\ ,$ and this is zero unless $\ c_j=r_i\ .$ Thus, if $\ r_1<c_1\ ,$ then the first row of $\ A_{t\times t}\ $ is
$$
\pmatrix{a_{r_1c_1}&a_{r_1c_2}&\dots& a_{r_1c_1}}=\pmatrix{0&0&\dots&0}\ ,
$$
so the minor, $\ \mu\ed\det\big(A_{t\times t}\big)\ ,$ corresponding to the matrix $\ A_{t\times t}\ $ must then be zero. Likewise, if $\ r_1>c_1\ ,$ then the first column of $\ \det\big(A_{t\times t}\big)\ $ would be zero.  Thus, $\ \mu=0\ $ unless $\ r_1=c_1\ .$ Repeating this argument successively for the pairs $\ \big(r_2,c_2\big), \big(r_3,c_3\big) \dots,\big(r_t,c_t\big)\ $ shows by induction that $\ \mu=0\ $ unless $\ r_j=c_j\ $ for $\ 1\le j\le t\ $—that is, unless $\ A_{t\times t}=\text{diag}\big\{k_{r_1},k_{r_2} \dots,k_{r_t}\big\}\ ,$ and hence $\ \mu=\prod_\limits{i=1}^t k_{r_i}\ .$ But if $\ t>\big|\big\{i\,|\,k_i\ne0\big\}\big|\ $ then at least one of $\ k_{r_1},k_{r_2} \dots,k_{r_t}\ $ must be zero and therefore $\ \mu=0\ .$ Conversely, if $\ t\le$$\,\big|\big\{i\,|\,k_i\ne0\big\}\big|\ $ then there is a submultiset $\ \big\{k_{i_1},k_{i_j},\dots,k_{i_t}\big\}\ $ of the multiset $\ \big\{k_1,k_2,\dots,k_n\big\}\ $ with  $\ i_1<i_2<\dots<i_t\ $ and $\ k_{i_j}\ne0\ $ for $\ 1\le j\le t\ ,$ and
$$
\det\big(\text{diag}\big\{k_{i_1},k_{i_2} \dots,k_{i_t}\big\}\big)=\prod_\limits{j=1}^t k_{i_j}
$$
is a non-zero minor of $\ A\ $ of degree $\ t\ .$ It follows from all of this that there exist non-zero minors of $\ A\ $ of degree $\ t\ $ if and only if $\ t\le\big|\big\{i\,|\,k_i\ne0\big\}\big|\ ,$ and that
$$
\gcd\left\{\prod_\limits{j=1}^tk_{i_j}\,\big|\,i_1<i_2<\dots<i_t\right\}
$$
is the gcd of all such minors.
Therefore, if
$$
S=\text{diag}\big\{\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\dots,\sigma_n\big\}
$$
is the Smith normal form of $\ A\ ,$ then $\ \sigma_1=\gcd\big\{k_1,$$\,k_2,$$\,\dots,$$\,k_n\big\}\ $ and
\begin{align}
\sigma_t&=\cases{\frac{\gcd\big\{\prod_\limits{j=1}^tk_{i_j}\,\big|\,i_1<i_2<\dots<i_t\big\}}{\gcd\big\{\prod_\limits{j=1}^{t-1}k_{i_j}\,\big|\,i_1<i_2<\dots<i_{t-1}\big\}}&if $\ \big|\big\{i\,|\,k_i\ne0\big\}\big|\ge t$\\
0&otherwise}
\end{align}
for $\ 2\le t\le n\ .$ For even moderately large $\ n\ ,$ this isn't a very useful formula, however, because the size of the set $\ \Big\{\prod_\limits{j=1}^tk_{i_j}\,\Big|\,i_1<$$\,i_2<$$\,\dots<$$\,i_t\Big\}\ $ is $\ {n\choose t}\ .$
$\,^\color{red}{\dagger}$ These are well known results, whose proofs can be found in any sufficiently comprehensive treatise on the subject (Morris Newman's Integral Matrices, for example, pp.$25$-$29$).

I can't figure out how to get this result. Can you show more details?

The results referred to in the first paragraph are well known. Proofs of them aren't at all difficult, but since some can be found in any sufficiently comprehensive treatise on the subject, I'm not willing to regurgitate any here. I've instead cited a reference where you can find some.  For the rest, I've added more details of why the formula I've given holds in tge case when $\ A\ $ is disgonal.

Computing SNF for diagonal matrices is functionally the same as for an arbitrary matrix. I'll use an example for this, say
$$ A  = (a_{ij}) = \begin{pmatrix}4 && \\ &17& \\ &&-2\end{pmatrix}, $$
where we omit zeros for readability. We are allowed to use elementary row and column operations over the integers, i.e.:

E1: Swapping two rows (resp. columns),
E2: Negating a row (resp. column),
E3: Adding an integer multiple of one row (resp. column) to another

I'll use this example to outline the algorithm I was taught. The first 'goal' should be to get the entry with the smallest absolute value (in this case $-2$) to be in the $a_{11}$ position, and to ensure it is positive. To do this, we repeatedly use operations E1 and E3:
$$ \begin{pmatrix}4 && \\ &17& \\ &&-2\end{pmatrix} \xrightarrow{\textrm{E1}\times 2} \begin{pmatrix} -2&&\\&17&\\&&4 \end{pmatrix} \xrightarrow{\textrm{E3}} \begin{pmatrix}2&&\\&17&\\&&4\end{pmatrix}.  $$
Our next 'goal' is to reduce $a_{11}$ to a common divisor of each $a_{ii}$, which will turn out to be the greatest common divisor. If $a_{11}$ is already a common divisor then we can skip this step, but in our example it is not.
For each $a_{ii}$ that $a_{11}$ does not divide, we add row $1$ to row $i$ (E3) and then by the Euclidean algorithm, there is $q_i,r_i \in \mathbb Z_{\geq 0}$ such that $r_i<a_{11}$ and $a_{ii} = q_ia_{11}+r_i$. In our case $q_2 =8, r_2 = 1$. We then use E3 to take $q_i$ lots of column $1$ from column $i$, and use E1 repeatedly to move the smallest value back to $a_{11}$
$$ \begin{pmatrix}2&&\\&17&\\&&4\end{pmatrix} \xrightarrow{\textrm{E3}} \begin{pmatrix}2&&\\2&17&\\&&4\end{pmatrix} \xrightarrow{\textrm{E3}} \begin{pmatrix}2&-16&\\2&1&\\&&4\end{pmatrix} \xrightarrow{\textrm{E1}\times 2} \begin{pmatrix} 1&2&\\-16&34&\\&&4 \end{pmatrix}. $$
From here we wish to remove any non-zero elements in row $1$ and column $1$. Sparing the details, repeatedly applying E3 gives
$$ \begin{pmatrix} 1&2&\\-16&34&\\&&4 \end{pmatrix} \xrightarrow{\textrm{E3}\times 2} \begin{pmatrix}1&&\\&34&\\&&4\end{pmatrix}. $$
We then repeat this entire process on the submatrix $B$ formed from deleting row $1$ and column $1$, in our case
$$ A \to \begin{pmatrix}1 & \\ & B\end{pmatrix},\quad B = \begin{pmatrix}34 & \\ & 4\end{pmatrix}. $$
Applying this procedure to $B$, we obtain
$$ B \to \begin{pmatrix}2 & \\ & 68\end{pmatrix}, $$
which is itself in SNF. So the SNF of $A$ is given by
$$ S = \begin{pmatrix}1&&\\&2&\\&&68\end{pmatrix}. $$
Formally, these elementary row (resp. column) operations are encoded with left (resp. right) multiplication by elementary matrices, and tracking these elementary matrices gives you the matrices $P, Q$ such that $S=PAQ$.

Thank you for your answer. But rather than algorithm, I am more interested in representing Smith normal form of diagonal matrix by its diagonal elements. For example, if $A=diag {a_1,\dots,a_n}$, the first elements of its Smith normal form is $gcd(a_1,\dots,a_n)$. I want to know if we can represent each element of Smith normal form of diagonal in similar way.

Provided that your Smith normal form is defined up to units (as it is for a general PID, for example) you do not need E1. and E2. This way, the matrices $P$ and $Q$ are of determinant $1$.
